# Yearly price increase loop? Stuck on nested loop

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops, jcreator

I'm trying to write a program that uses scanner keyboard to input these values and uses a loop to have them increase (2006-2010, year-year, & an increase in price, 90-100, etc.)

The output is supposed to look like this:

> ```
> Enter the current Mars bar price in cents: 90
> Enter the expected yearly price increase: 15
> Enter the start year: 2006
> Enter the end year: 2010
> Price in 2006: 90 cents
> Price in 2007: 105 cents
> Price in 2008: 120 cents
> Price in 2009: 135 cents
> Price in 2010: 150 cents
> ```

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO, add your application code
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the current Mars bar price in cents: ");
        int m = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the expected yearly price increase: ");
        int p = keyboard.nextInt();
        int a = m+p;

        int count = 1;
        System.out.print("Enter the start year: ");
        int start = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the end year: ");
        int end = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++){
            System.out.print("Price in " +i+ ": " +m);start++;
    }
}
```

and it allows me to have the year increasing to the set amount (again like 2006-2010) but I'm stuck on having the price increase along with it by the set amount, I assume it would be a nested loop but I'm not sure how to write it.

(I assume a nested loop because that's what we're learning right now.)

If anyone has any advice on what I could write, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: `System.out.print("Price in " +i+ ": " +m);start++;` looks like the price (m) isn't changing?

Comment: What is the point of `int a = m+p;` if you never use it?

Comment: You can look at [this example](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/nested-loop). I am sure you'll figure out the solution yourself!

Comment: @ Mohammad, the price isn't changing, no. I'm not sure how I would write it to get it to change, this is only the code I have so far that allows the year to increase, but I don't know how to get the price to increase as well.

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS I'm still trying to figure out how to get the price to change. That was something I was messing with, haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to sum the `expected yearly price increase` to the `current price` in each iteration of your loop, it'd be something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Problem_2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO, add your application code
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the current Mars bar price in cents: ");
    int m = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the expected yearly price increase: ");
    int p = keyboard.nextInt();

    int count = 1;
    System.out.print("Enter the start year: ");
    int start = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the end year: ");
    int end = keyboard.nextInt();

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++){
        System.out.print("Price in " +i+ ": " +m);
        m += p; // sum expected price for each iteration

  }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I feel stupid looking at it now lol, I was putting the variables in all the wrong places. Thank you again!